# What is build object file extension in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

When I build java object class in a project, build file will be created with .class extension and human unreadable; What about swift build files?

example:

```
car.java  --> build --> car.class
```

what would be after build?

```
car.swift --> build --> ?
```

Comment: I think you are interested in this article: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/manual-swift-understanding-the-swift-objective-c-build-pipeline/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compilation process is a bit different with Swift to Java, so there isn't necessarily a direct equivalent.

As the build proceeds though each Swift file will get compiled in to an 'Object' file, ending in a `.o` extension. Then once they're all built they get linked together to form the binary. If you unpick an iOS app's IPA file, you won't see the individual `.o` files like how you can see the `.class` files inside a Java jar file.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I know is that Swift uses LLVM just like Objective-C.

**So in Java, we have this (source: W3schools).**
[image]

**And here, for Swift (source: Swift.org)**

[image]

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

**Mach-O format**

[[LLVM]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66844588/4770877)

In iOS world every sources file - `.m`, `.h`, `.swift` are compiled into executable byte code that is understandable by CPU. These files are also called `Mach object`(`.o`) - `ABI Mach-O`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271017/4770877) file which contains nexts grouped bytes with a meta-information

- Mach-O header - general information like cpu type([CPU_TYPE](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-836/include/mach/machine.h))
- Load Commands - table of contents
- Raw segment data - code

  - __LLVM - bitcode[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66845532/4770877)

This groups are repeated for every architecture(Universal library)[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)

```
`*.swift` -> `*.o` (Mach-O object file)
```

For example if you created a static library - `myLibrary.a`. You can use `nm`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214503/4770877) command to display name list (symbol table).

```
nm path/myLibrary.a
```

As a result you will see a list of `*.o` files with methods, variables names etc.

To investigate Mach-O file you can use `otool`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56065561/4770877)

[[Mach-O Type]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035316/4770877)

[[Xcode build process]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216120/4770877)